# Can I use an external bluetooth mic for android applications?

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

I need to use external microphone (from bluetooth headset) in application with voice input.
Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't just tried it?

Comment: Of cause, I try, but only built-in microphone was active. But I need external.

Answer (score 1):

Appears that Android still lacks some skills regarding Bluetooth headset to Voice Input capabilities. I couldn't make it work either.

But there's an APP for everything, and this is no different ;)

[Skyvi (Siri for Android)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluetornadosf.smartypants&hl=en) available from Google Play Store:

**Key Features:**

> - Voice Texting
> - Fast find and call places
> - Get directions
> - Call Contacts
> - Play music
> - Local weather and time
> - Fun chats, witty remarks, tells jokes
> - Access Facebook with voice
> - Access Twitter with voice
> - **Text by Voice**                                                       <- *what you seek*
> - Tweet or Update Facebook with Voice
> - Ask questions with voice
> - Car Mode